# How to find out the number of times an element in Array1 is present in Array2

Tags: ruby, algorithm

What is the best way to accomplish this in Ruby? `Array1` contains few numbers `Array2` contains unsorted numbers. We want to find out how often each element of `Array1` shows up in `Array2`.

Example:

```
Array1 = [0,1,2,3]

Array2 = [0,0,0,3,3,3,2,1,0,3,6,1,3]

Result = {"0"=>4, "1"=>2, "2"=>1, "3"=>5}
```

Is there a better optimal way to do this than:

- picking each element of `Array1`
- iterating over `Array2`
- incrementing a counter each time elements match

Example just shows few number but I want to find out best way to do this for a very large array set.

Comment: It seems to me like similar to sorting algorithm so the efficiency at the most you can get is in order of the sorting algorithms that are present.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm may be `nlogn` if you use Mergesort principle.

Comment: @uDaY: You can actually do that in `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group_by` to count the items in `array2`:

```
irb(main):001:0> array1 = [0,1,2,3]
=> [0, 1, 2, 3]
irb(main):002:0> array2 = [0,0,0,3,3,3,2,1,0,3,6,1,3]
=> [0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 6, 1, 3]
irb(main):003:0> h = Hash[array2.group_by { |x| x }.map { |k, v| [k, v.size] }]
=> {0=>4, 3=>5, 2=>1, 1=>2, 6=>1}
```

If you want, you can then extract the sub-hash with the keys from `array1` (but I don't think this is really necessary):

```
irb(main):004:0> h.select { |k,_| array1.include?(k) }
=> {0=>4, 3=>5, 2=>1, 1=>2}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers in array are not very large then you can make an array with size as the greatest element of any of the array. Then iterate the array once and increment the position by 1. i.e.

```
Suppose the largest element in array 2 is 10
declare an array with length 10 i.e a[10] and initialize the array with 0
Now suppose you find 1 in array2 then increment a[1]
If you find 4 in array2 then increment a[4] and so on
Then again iterate over array1 once and match the corresponding element
```

I have not considered the language as Ruby but if you have got the idea then it is fairly easy to implement in any language.
Complexity: O(n)

Comment: `group_by` uses a very similar concept, only it stores the items in a hash table rather than an array (writing to a hash-table is also `O(1)`, however).

Comment: like in many other interpreted programming languages ruby doesn't treat arrays as instances with an immutable size but more like a merge between classic arrays and lists.

Comment: @robustus: You'd still need to initialize the items here, so "declare an array of length 10" can be interpreted as something like `a = [0]*10`, which seems sensible and results in a classical vector data structure with `O(1)` access to its members.

Comment: @robustus I am not familiar with Ruby so I just explained a normal algorithm. Its upon you how you implement it.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [0,1,2,3]
b = [0,0,0,3,3,3,2,1,0,3,6,1,3]

a.inject({}){|h,i| h[i] = b.count(i); h}
#=> {0=>4, 1=>2, 2=>1, 3=>5}
```

or

```
Hash[a.map{|i| [i,b.count(i)]}]
#=> {0=>4, 1=>2, 2=>1, 3=>5}
```